# Error when install dompdf in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I run this to install dompdf:

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

And the error looks like this:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-dompdf ^0.8.1 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-dompdf[v0.8.1].
    - Conclusion: remove dompdf/dompdf v0.7.0
    - Conclusion: don't install dompdf/dompdf v0.7.0
    - barryvdh/laravel-dompdf v0.8.1 requires dompdf/dompdf ^0.8 -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[v0.8.0, v0.8.1].
    - Can only install one of: dompdf/dompdf[v0.8.0, v0.7.0].
    - Can only install one of: dompdf/dompdf[v0.8.1, v0.7.0].
    - Installation request for dompdf/dompdf (locked at v0.7.0) -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[v0.7.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Any of you know what's wrong or what should i do?

Comment: can you try to remove dompdf and install again using composer remove barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Comment: the dompdf package is not installed because of that error. i have no idea to fix it @iCoders

Comment: @Dimas.let me install dompdf in laravel 5.4 and will check once

Comment: ok, i'll wait for it :) @iCoders

Comment: for me installed successfully.  "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.1",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/passport": "^2.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "nesbot/carbon": "^1.22",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-html": "1.0",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "7.2"

Comment: in mine error, i don't know what is the problem @iCoders

Answer (score 1):

The error message states that **barryvdh/laravel-dompdf** package require **"dompdf/dompdf": "^0.8"** which is newer version but you have **dompdf/dompdf v0.7.0** which is older version installed.

So you should try to remove old version of dompdf to install new version.